# Is QUADPACK kept up to date with the state-of-the-art in numerical integration?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Are people still actively working on QUADPACK in order to incorporate new advances in numerical integration, or does the library still rely only on the algorithms that were around at the time it was initially written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unmaintained, the last update I can see is from [1987](http://www.netlib.org/quadpack/changes). That being said, 1D numerical integration has not changed incredibly rapidly over the past 30 years. (High dimensional quadrature would be hopelessly out of date.) The only algorithm which is obviously lacking is the [double exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanh-sinh_quadrature) quadrature for integrands lying in Hardy spaces.

Curtis-Clenshaw and Gauss-Kronrod are workhorses that are likely to be useful for centuries. However, the main problem with QUADPACK is it is written in Fortran 77. This wouldn't be a problem if people were still reading and learning Fortran 77, but they aren't. [g77](http://www.kilmnj.com/g77/) isn't even maintained, so cannot generate newer instruction sets. So you will be in for some serious work to get working projects with raw QUADPACK. scipy maintains a QUADPACK [wrapper](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html), which is very easy to use, so you can avoid the hassle of learning Fortran 77.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. Yes, I've been using it through scipy. Are there any other libraries that implement the more modern methods for high dimensional quadrature, or do people code these for themselves when they work with them?

Comment: If you do code a high-dimensional quadrature routine, please contribute it to an open-source project so I can use it to! But I would estimate that implementing a sparse grid or importance sampled Monte-Carlo integration, parallelized and optimized would take a solid month. Check out the gsl for a solid Monte Carlo integrator.